# Python script stops executing after file browse window is opened

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Python script stops executing after a button which opens up a file upload window is pressed.

Here is what I have tried:

1. I know for sure that the python script stops after the file selection window is opened.
   I only coded that section and the script stopped.
2. I ran the autoIt script via a new python script after my previous script stopped executing to check my autoIt script and it works as expected.

   ```
   #file_btn--button used to open file upload window
   file_btn = wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "some_XPath")))

   file_btn.click()

   #script stops here

   autoit.run("my_autoIt.exe")

   """more code""""
   ```

What I want is to keep the script running after,

Python script --> Opens File Browser --> Runs AutoIt --> Back to Python Script

Comment: Can you share the html of the file upload `browse` field. I believe you should have an input with `type=file` (most of the cases it's hidden), which will make the job easy to upload the file rather using the AutoIt. You just have to pass the file location to that input.

Comment: I believe that will not work as I have tried using send_keys to try and make the upload, but the field does not accept texts like that.

Comment: try with adding some delay statement after running autoit script. It may solve your problem.

Comment: @shreyashsharma You really should revisit using `send_keys` to upload the file. The W3C WebDriver Specification says that calling `click` on an `<input type="file">‘ element should throw an exception. If the driver for the browser you’re using doesn’t throw an exception in that case now, it’s likely that it will someday.

Comment: I was able to solve it by calling the script's function(which was stopping) through another script, then calling any more functions from the calling script.